# str_replace, replacing word with div causes break in p tag

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, str-replace

The code below searches WordPress content for words and replaces these words with a link and a div. It creates a problem where the div closes the `<p>` tag it was inserted into.

```
$myposts = get_pages(args...);
$replace = array();
$i = 1;

foreach( $myposts as $post ) {
    setup_postdata($post);
    $replace[get_the_title()] = '<a href="#popupBasic' . $i . '" data-rel="popup">' . get_the_title() . '</a><div data-role="popup" class="tooltipBox" id="popupBasic' . $i . '">' . get_the_content() . '</div>';
    $i++;
}

$text = str_replace(array_keys($replace), $replace, $text);
```

Why is the str_replace breaking the `<p>` tag like this?

```
<div>
    <p>Some random text thats been <a href="#" class="link">cutt</a></p><div style="display: none;"><!-- placeholder --></div> off.<p></p>
</div>
```

If it cannot be fixed within PHP, can we fix this with jQuery?
I want to put back the word thats been cut off, in this case " off." into the `<p>` tag that is closed after the link. And also remove the empty `<p>` tag in the end.

Comment: This is appropriate behavior. The question is, what do you want the end result to be?

Comment: Why are you str_replace'ing on what is clearly a DOMDocument

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem: It clearly isn't, he's doing server-side PHP.

Comment: [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php).

Comment: If your div NEEDS to be a div, append it to the end of your document and position it absolutely. If it doesn't, use a span instead and use CSS to make it `display:block` if needed.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: moonwave99 linked to what I was getting at: just _parse_ HTML instead of treating it like a string

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem: I think it would be problematic to introduce that into the middle of a WordPress page. Or at least costly, performance-wise. The whole ethos of the WordPress code is textual. (I'm not saying it *should* be, just that it is...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`p` elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-p-element.html#the-p-element) contain [*phrasing content*](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/content-models.html#phrasing-content-1). [`div`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-div-element.html#the-div-element) is not valid in phrasing content, it's valid in [*flow content*](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/content-models.html#flow-content-1). (Putting a `div` inside a `p` is like putting a `p` inside a `p`.) So the browser is making the best of invalid markup.

Try using a [`span`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-span-element.html#the-span-element) rather than a `div`.

Comment: Thanks, I copied the markup from here. http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/popup/index.html

Comment: @halliewuud: That markup has a `p` inside a `div`. That's valid, `div` can contain `p` (the contents of a `div` are flow content). Your markup is trying to do it the other way around.

Comment: @TJ That is because the str_replace is replacing a word inside a <p> tag. And the code I pasted is generated by jquery mobile.

Comment: @halliewuud: I don't see anything in the jQuery mobile stuff you linked to that's trying to put a `div` inside a `p`. For what *you're* doing, as opposed to what *they're* doing, a `span` is more appropriate.